# How can i count numbers greater than 0 in a part of colums row wise in a dataframe and save it in a column

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image]

I want to count number of columns  that have value greater than 0 row wise for specific column selected like

monday,tuesday,wednesday, thursday,friday,saturday,sunday and save it in a separate column

for example number of rows in `id_recipient 0` is 2: `(monday,saturday)`, for `id_recipient 1` is also 2: `(monday, tuesday)` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
dict = {'ID_recipient':[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
        'monday': [13, 10, 9, 12, 9], 
        'tuesday':[0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        'wednesday':[0,0,0,0,1],
        'thursday':[0,0,0,0,0],
        'friday':[0,0,0,0,0],
        'saturday':[1,0,1,0,0],
        'sunday':[0,0,0,0,0]} 
  
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict) 
  
df
```

To set up following DataFrame:
[image]

Now I create a list of all the days of week columns:

```
daysofweek = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday',
              'saturday', 'sunday']
```

Now I create a new column that sums up the logical value for all days of week columns across all rows (vectorised so it's much quicker that using e.g. .iterrows() )

```
df['No_rows'] = (test_df[daysofweek] > 0).sum(axis=1)
```

This gives me the correct output as you desired:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

We can use `DataFrame.ne` which stands for `not equal` and `DataFrame.sum` over the column axis (`axis=1`).

I assumed your dataframe is called `df`

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']
df['count'] = df[columns].ne(0).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution as it uses native .ne(0)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line simply like so:

```
df['count'] = [len(list(filter(list(df['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday','friday','saturday','sunday'].iloc[x]), lambda y: y > 0))) for x in range(len(df['monday']))]
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

We used applymap with on the fly function, if x>0 than 1, otherwise 0.
We've summed it over axis 1 and put it under 'count' new column

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']
df['count'] = df[columns].applymap(lambda x : 1 if x > 0 else 0).values.sum(axis=1)
```